# Alarm Controller is sending me unwanted notifications, ads

Tags: malware

From many days I am getting unwanted ads and notifications. I uninstalled many app, and also did a factory reset also, After searching, I found *Alarm Controller* may be the culprit. As I lock my screen and the then try to unlock it again, the on-screen ads blinks all the time. I had a screenshot of the app

[image: Alarm controller running]

Please help me to get rid of these ads. Let me know if any more information needed.

Comment: It's a [known malware](http://www.avgthreatlabs.com/ww-en/android-app-reports/app/com.al.alarm.controller/). First thing first, can you uninstall it? Are you rooted? Seems it's installed as [home launcher](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/nexus/Qx0xjkMQM5A;context-place=forum/Nexus), can you change it to other launcher?

Comment: No i cant uninstall it. also it automatically install hola launcher. so i can change my launcher to hola launcer

Comment: Is there any message when you failed to uninstall it? Also, when you change to Hola Launcher, does the ads appear again? (I know it's not the perfect solution, but if it can work as workaround for now..)..... so, try turning off the Accessibility setting for Alarm Controller. Also, look at Security - Device Administrators and disable it (if exists). Then try to uninstall it again.

Comment: I think recent versions of android has capability to **turn off** notifications for particular apps.

Comment: No it simply says uninstall unsuccessfull, No Still i get the ads either i switch to hola launcher, I am always turning off the accessibility but as i lock and unlock the phone it again turn on automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last I got a solution or workaround, I installed [NoRoot Data Firewall](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jianjia.firewall) and then created a VPN on my own mobile and now I am having full authority to whom to give access to network and whom to not.

This is just the workaround I found, it doesn't remove the Malware. But it worked and get me out of the frustration.

Answer (score 0):

Use firewall to restrict the network. Try this:

1. Install firewall app (e.g. [CM Data Manager - Speed Test](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cmcm.flowmonitor))
2. Open the app, go to Network Firewall setting. You will see all the apps are unrestricted
3. Set *Alarm Controller* to restricted app: tap *ON* to restrict the app. It will stop the unwanted notification & ads in your phone.

Comment: I will try it today

Comment: I Tried this solution but it Creates a firewall with 2g network and not with wifi . So it didn't worked for me. Noroot firewall worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation ..I  have tried all the stuffs suggested here..
1) Using CM Data Manager - Speed Test - It does not work. It only allows to Create restriction at firewall with 2g network and not with wifi.
2) Turning Off the Accessibility option in Settings for Alarm Controller - is again temporary solution as the it gets turned "ON" by itself with few minutes.. Malware is doing it i guess.
In the meantime the malware is getting strong. Now the alarm controller is no more version 2.0 like before and has updated itself to 4.0 (i hv no idea when and how) . Apart from installing several random apps (hola launcher quite repeatedly) by itself now this malware is creating some shortcuts with porno icons which on clicking takes you to some linkup websites and/or result in some downloads.. its getting really frustrating.

Comment: have you tried the workaround i followed? (In upper comment)

Comment: No i havent.. I need to try it.. 
BTW Did u say, u tried Factory Reset without restore (google apps ) option yourself and still face the issue..

Another thing, I got update for Android marshmallow 6.0 but am unable to install.. During installtion it erros out.. Did you (or anyone else) face this issue. Please confirm

Answer (score -1):

Just click stop button and power on/off your phone to reset from scratch. Click Settings and you will get various options to deal with. It's very simple and you won't get such ads, all the best !!

IF NOT, than you should go for Factory Re-set of this phone, thanks.

Comment: I tried all the things.. but no luck

Answer (score -1):

- Turn Off the *Accessibility* option in Settings
- Settings → Applications → Alarm Controller → Clear data & Clear cache  → Disable and Force Stop.  I tried it and it works for me.