# Unable to remove malware

Tags: malware, antivirus

I have android tablet and every time i open a browser, any browser, it automatically opens pages with ads or making me download things. Obviously the tablet got a malware but i am not able to remove it. I installed Avast, Avira, Malwarbites, CCleaner but none of them was able to remove this malware.
Any other ideas how to get rid of this malware? 
Usually in which location the viruses for android resides? In Windows most of them are in Temp folder but i am not very familiar with android.

Comment: The best way to remove ~99% of all malware is to simply factory reset the device. Only a small fraction of malware apps really protect themselves from those solutions, because they require more work than needed for their purpose.

Comment: Isn't that a little drastic solution? I mean if i reset the device i will loose all of my settings and apps i have installed, right?
And by the way, i am seeing ads on every other app i open, they appear at the top or at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: I know from a friend, that this is the easiest way to remove any malware. Plus, it allows the system to reconfigure itself and usually restores some of the original speed it had after the first boot. You could always try to find out if you have any suspicious app on your device and remove it by hand.

Comment: What tablet do you have? Also, save all your important files before you consider factory resetting.

Comment: The tablet is not a top brand, but the android version is 4.4.2.

Comment: Seems it's related to the recent Alarm Controller malware. If it's, related post: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/129052/alarm-controller-is-sending-me-unwanted-notifications-ads

Answer (score 1):

I reset the factory settings: **settings>backup&reset>factory data reset** and now the ads disappeared. I also checked "opt out of interest based ads" in google settings app.

Comment: Please edit your answer to include steps you used so others may follow along. Also to make it a complete answer.

Comment: "Opt-out of interest based ads" won't help this issue actually. It just instructs Google to display any ads, not related to your interest based on your history.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the malware removers for Android are of limited value because Android makes things run in their own little sectioned-off area of memory. Sometimes, a malicious app may slip through the protection or trick you into allowing it past.  Unfortunately, the same setup that tries to block malicious apps also will prevent "good" apps from trying to fix it.

One of the easiest ways I can think of to force you to default to a malicious web page is either changing the browser's default web page or creating shortcuts on your home screen so that you think you're starting your browser but you're actually going straight to the malicious web site.

First of all, try launching the browser directly from the Apps menu (where you go to see all the apps installed).  It may be that the malicious software created shortcuts on your home screen that look like browsers but aren't.  If launching it from the Apps menu works normally then delete all the copies on your home page and drag the App from the menu to create a "fresh" one.

If that doesn't work then something may have changed all the browers' home pages.  Go into the settings for each browser and look for an option to set  your home page (there's a bunch of different terms: home page, default page, starting page.  Look for something like that) and set it something innocuous like Google.

Answer (score -3):

The spams and ads didn't just come out of nowhere. Many times it's the junk app that you have downloaded. Crappy apps produce spam, ad, makes your phone act up, lag, etc.
Sounds like you have an app that produces needless ads. Go over what apps you have installed, and nit pick through them, and uninstall the app that you would think to be producing the ads. 
another best way to remove malware from an Android would be to, unsurprisingly, install a malware removal app. Just be sure to install a reputable one. How silly would it be if you accidentally installed malware while trying to install a malware remover? Here are some free ones that you may want to check out:
3 60 mobile security. 
Avg mobile security. 
It will surely help you if not then try this
Back up all your pictures (and music and videos) to your Google account. Google+ is a great place to store your pictures, drop your videos in your YouTube account, and you can store up to 20,000 songs in your Google Play Music account. Utilize this free space Google gives you, even if it's just to store a few things while you pour digital bleach on everything.

Take the SD card out of your phone if it has one. Visit a computer and wipe and repartition it using the built-in software for disk management. Don't save anything — you need to be brutal to make sure anything nasty gets nuked. But first try Checking your app list. Then use tool if that's not helping.

Comment: How shall that help removing malware? Are you suggesting malware just sits in the cache folder? I very much doubt that. Your suggestion doesn't hurt – but probably doesn't help either.

Comment: Wiping cache didn't help. Still looking for other solutions to try, before reseting the factory settings.

Comment: Check the answer now

Comment: Please refrain from your condescending editorial comments when providing an answer. Just provide facts, references, links  and/or personal experiences. Unless edited this should be a comment, not an answer.